Model the Policy for policy gradient for the 2D cutting stock problem
I need to implement a policy gradient algorithms (actor-critic) for the 2D cutting stock problem with varied size stocks. However I'm new to machine learning so I still have no clue how to design the policy.

There are 25 product type, each has demand at most 20.
There are 100 stocks, each stock is represented as a 100 by 100 grid. Each grid element is either -2 (not in stock), -1 (in a stock), or a non-negative integer (the index of the product placed on the stock)

Thank you!

Ok, can you provide a brief description of the problem and what the goal is? Thanks for providing already some info about the problem but you're not explaining what the goal is.

Hello nbro! The goal is to minimize the trim loss, or minimize the total waste area of the stock used!
